# SQL Subquery Join and Sum

Tags: sql, subquery, microsoft-sal

I have Table 1 & 2 with common Column name ID in both.

Table 1 has duplicate entries of rows which I was able to trim using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

Table 2 has duplicate numeric entries(dollarspent) for ID's which I needed and was able to sum up:

```
Table 1         Table 2 
------------   ------------------
ID     spec    ID       Dol1     Dol2
54      A      54        1         0
54      A      54        2         1
55      B      55        0         2
56      C      55        3         0
```

-I need to join these two queries into one so I get a resultant JOIN of Table 1 & Table 2 ON column ID, (a) without duplicates in Table 1 & (b) Summed $ values  from Table 2

For eg:

```
NewTable
----------------------------------------
ID     Spec          Dol1           Dol2
54      A             3               1
55      B             3               2
```

Notes : No. of rows in Table 1 and 2 are not the same.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, @ryan199004. Would you be able to repost this and format it properly? You might consider going to: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables for some help.

If you'd like, take a picture and I can try and help.

Comment: The real question here is why do you have duplicates on ID in Table 1 in the first place. Any solution developed is likely addressing a symptom and not root cause. But given the data is appropriate... solutions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a derived table to get the distinct values from table1 and simply join to table 2 and use aggregation.

The issue you have is you have a M:M relationship between table1 and table2.  You need it to be a 1:M for the summations to be accurate.  Thus we derive t1 from table1 by using a select distinct to give us the unique records in the 1:M relationship (assuming specs are same for each ID)

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Spec, Sum(T2.Dol1) as Dol1, sum(T2.Dol2) as Dol2
FROM (SELECT distinct ID, spec
      FROM table1) T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
 on t2.ID = T1.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Spec
```

This does assume you only want records that exist in both.  Otherwise we may need to use an (LEFT, RIGHT, or FULL) outer join; depending on desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see your data, but you might want to try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM TblOne

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT ID, SUM(Dol)
FROM TblTwo
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre-aggregate table 2 and then join:

```
select t1.id, t1.spec, t2.dol1, t2.dol2
from (select t2.id, sum(dol1) as dol1, sum(dol2) as dol2
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.id
     ) t2 join
     (select distinct t1.id, t1.spec
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

For your data examples, you don't need to pre-aggregate table 2.  This gives the correct sums -- albeit in multiple rows -- if `table1` has multiple specs for a given id.